# Java using methods and calling them

Tags: java, methods

```
package savingsaccount;

public class SavingsAccount
{
    static double AnnualInterestRate;
    static double savingsBalance;

    public static double setInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
        annualInterestRate=.04;
        return annualInterestRate;
    }

    public static double calcnewbalance(double newsaverbal) {
        AnnualInterestRate = setInterestRate(AnnualInterestRate);
        newsaverbal = (newsaverbal * AnnualInterestRate/12) + newsaverbal;
        return newsaverbal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Savings    Account    Balances");
        System.out.println("Month    Saver1    Saver2");
        double saver1=2000;
        double saver2=3000;
        for(int n=1; n<=13; n=n+1) {
            if(n<10) {
                savingsBalance = calcnewbalance(saver1);
                saver1 = savingsBalance;
                System.out.printf( " "+ n + "        %.2f   " , saver1);
                savingsBalance = calcnewbalance(saver2);
                saver2 = savingsBalance;
                System.out.printf("%.2f%n" , savingsBalance);

            } else if(n<13 && n>9) {
                savingsBalance = calcnewbalance(saver1);
                saver1 = savingsBalance;
                System.out.printf(n + "        %.2f   " , saver1);
                savingsBalance = calcnewbalance(saver2);
                saver2 = savingsBalance;
                System.out.printf("%.2f%n" , saver2);
            } else {
                savingsBalance = calcnewbalance(saver1);
                saver1 = savingsBalance;

                System.out.printf(n + "        %.2f   " , saver1);
                savingsBalance = calcnewbalance(saver2);

                saver2 = savingsBalance;
                System.out.printf("%.2f%n" , saver2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I am trying to set the interest rate is the "else" part of the code to a different value. I want to use setInterestRate only in the equation calc new balance.

Is there a way for setInterestRate to know when it is being called a 13th time and instantiate a new value for the interest rate?

Comment: use a variable of type `int` and increase it , if the variable equal 13 you launch the function?

Comment: Since the code in `else` will be executed only when `n == 13` you can simply implement whatever logic you want there and it'll get executed on the 13th time.

Comment: well the problem is that calcnewbalance doesnt know it is in an else statement. i need setinterest to be on its own

Answer (score 0):

A primitive is not an `Object`, and is not instantiated. Also, making these static is completely missing the point -

```
static double savingsBalance;
static double AnnualInterestRate;
public static double setInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
    annualInterestRate=.04;
    return annualInterestRate;
}
```

Should be an accessor and a mutator (or a getter and setter),

```
private double annualInterestRate;
public void setInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
  this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
}
public double getInterestRate() {
  return this.annualInterestRate;
}
private double balance;
public double getBalance() {
  return balance;
}
```

Then

```
public double calcnewbalance(double balance) {
    AnnualInterestRate = setInterestRate(AnnualInterestRate); // 0.4 is always 0.4
    newsaverbal += (newsaverbal * getInterestRate()/12);
    return newsaverbal;
}
```

can be

```
public void applyInterest() {
    balance += (balance * getInterestRate()/12);
}
```

Next, a no-arg `SavingsAccount` constructor -

```
public SavingsAccount(double balance) {
  this.annualInterestRate = 0.04;
  this.balance = balance;
}
```

Finally in `main()`,

```
SavingsAccount sa = new SavingsAccount();
for (int = 0; i < 13; i++) {
  System.out.println(sa.getBalance());
  sa.applyInterest();
}
```

**Edit**

To change the interest rate on the 13th call, you could do -

```
private int interestCount = 0;
public void applyInterest() {
    if (interestCount++ > 12) {
      interestCount = 0;
      setInterestRate(0.05);
    }
    balance += (balance * getInterestRate()/12);
}
```

Comment: So how would i change from .4 to .5 after the 12th loop?